# MySQL - Find Orders placed by repeat customers vs. new customers over time

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an orders table that contains the orders_id, customers_email_address and date_purchased. I want to write a SQL query that will, for each line in the table, add a new field called 'repeat_order_count' that shows how many times this customer ordered before and including this order.

For example, if John ordered once before this order, the repeat_order_count would be 2 for this order, or in other words, this is the second time John has ordered.  The next order row I encounter for John will have a 3, and so on.  This will allow me to create a line graph that shows the number of orders placed by repeat customers over time. I can now go to a specific time in the past and figure out how many orders were placed by repeat customers during that time period:

```
SELECT 
      * 
FROM orders 
WHERE repeat_order_count > 1 
WHERE date_purchased = January 2014 --(simplifying things here)
```

I'm also able to determine now WHEN a customer became a repeat customer.

I can't figure out the query to solve this.  Or perhaps there may be an easier way to do this?

Comment: This is not normalized. In a database you should normalize it (in my opinion at least) where you use the `customer_id` rather than the `customers_email_address` so that if you update the customer, you update just once and not having to update multiple tables with his/her data in. Then if you would like to pull the information of the customer while in the `orders table` you can just do a join.

Comment: Good point.  We do use a customer_id, but I'm not including it here to simplify things.  There is a reason I wanted to use the email_address for this example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach to retrieving the specified result would be to use a correlated subquery in the SELECT list. This assumes that the customer identifier is `customers_email_address`, and that `date_purchased` is a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP` (or other canonical format), and that there are no duplicated values for the same customer (that is, the customer doesn't have two or more orders with the same `date_purchased` value.)

```
SELECT s.orders_id
     , s.customers_email_address
     , s.date_purchased 
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1)
           FROM orders p
          WHERE p.customers_email_address = s.customers_email_address
            AND p.date_purchased          < s.date_purchased
       ) AS previous_order_count
  FROM orders s
 ORDER
    BY s.customers_email_address
     , s.date_purchased
```

The correlated subquery will return 0 for the "first" order for a customer, and 1 for the "second" order. If you want to include the current order in the count, replace the `<` comparison operator with `<=` operator.

**FOLLOWUP**

For performance of that query, we need to be particulary concerned with the performance of the correlated subquery, since that is going to be executed for every row in the table. (A million rows in the table means a million executions of that query.) Having a suitable index available is going to be crucial.

For the query in my answer, I'd recommend trying an index like this:

```
ON orders (customers_email_address, date_purchased, orders_id)
```

With that index in place, we'd expect `EXPLAIN` to show the index being used by both the outer query, to satisfy the `ORDER BY` (No "Using filesort" in the `Extra` column), and as a covering index (no lookups to the pages in the underlying table, "Using index" shown in the `Extra` column.)

The answer I gave demonstrated just one approach. It's also possible to return an equivalent result using a join pattern, for example:

```
SELECT s.orders_id
     , s.customers_email_address
     , s.date_purchased
     , COUNT(p.orders_id)
  FROM orders s
  JOIN orders p
    ON p.customers_email_address = s.customers_email_address
   AND p.date_purchased         <= s.date_purchased
 GROUP
    BY s.customers_email_address
     , s.date_purchased
     , s.orders_id
 ORDER
    BY s.customers_email_address
     , s.date_purchased
     , s.orders_id
```

(This query is based on some additional information provided in a comment, which wasn't available before: `orders_id` is UNIQUE in the `orders` table.)

If we are guaranteed that `orders_id` of a "previous" order is less than the `orders_id` of a previous order, then it would be possible to use that column in place of the `date_purchased` column.  We'd want a suitable index available:

```
... ON orders (customers_email_address, orders_id, date_purchased)
```

NOTE: The *order* of the columns in the index is *important*.  With that index, we could do:

```
SELECT s.orders_id
     , s.customers_email_address
     , s.date_purchased
     , COUNT(p.orders_id)
  FROM orders s
  JOIN orders p
    ON p.customers_email_address = s.customers_email_address
   AND p.orders_id              <= s.orders_id
 GROUP
    BY s.customers_email_address
     , s.orders_id
 ORDER
    BY s.customers_email_address
     , s.orders_id
```

Again, we'd want to review the output from `EXPLAIN` to verify that the index is being used for both the join operation and the GROUP BY operation.

NOTE: With the inner join, we need to use a `<=` comparison, so we get at least one matching row back. We could either subtract 1 from that result, if we wanted a count of only "previous" orders (not counting the current order), or we could use an outer join operation with a `<` comparison, so we could get a row back with a count of 0.

Comment: This works perfectly.  Thank you!   It's amazing how fast you can get a well-qualified answer on this site.

Comment: It would also be possible to do 'p.orders_id < s.orders_id' since the order ids are always unique and in order. I wonder if that would make the query faster?

Comment: Any way to speed up this query if you had to do it for 1 million rows?

Comment: @user3761228: as long as there's an appropriate index define e.g. **`ON orders (customers_email_address,orders_id)`**, then the change you suggest would give reasonable performance. For the query in my answer, optimum performance would be obtained with a suitable index ... **`ON orders (customers_email_address,date_purchased)`**. That index would be used by both the correlated subquery and the outer query, avoiding an expensive "Using filesort" operation. (MySQL can use the index retrieve the rows "in order", without performing a sort operation.)

Comment: @user3761228: Use **`EXPLAIN`** to see what operations MySQL is performing for your query. With a million rows in the table, a million executions of the correlated subquery, and a million rows being returned, we're particularly concerned with the performance of those million executions of the correlated subquery, and concerned with avoiding a "Using filesort" operation. There are other query patterns which may give better performance, such as a JOIN.  I'll update my answer with an example of that.

Comment: Thank you again for your help.  When you use the "ON" syntax to create an index, do you mean using something like this:  CREATE INDEX index_name
ON table_name (column_name)

Comment: Just fyi--something must not be right with those followup queries.  Perhaps joining a massive table against itself is not working well.  I finally was able to test the original query you sent and it takes 1min 40 seconds to complete on a 1.1 million row table.  The followup queries are taking very long and I'm having to cancel them.  I think original seems the way to go even with 1.1 million queries running.  Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

when you are inserting into your orders table, for the column you have for your `OrderCount` you use a co-related sub-query.
eg:

```
select
    col1,
    col2,
    (isnull((select count(*) from orders where custID = @currentCustomer),0) + 1),
    col4
```

Note that you wouldn't be adding the field when the 2nd order is processed, the field would already exist and you would just be populating it.